# Java 7 Memory Model same as JSR-133?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I was re-reading the [JSR-133](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133) specification when I wondered if there were any changes that occurred in the Java 7 release. That is, if 133 was obsolete or still valid.

I didn't find anything on Google about changes in the memory model for Java 7, but I'm asking here just in case anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid w/o plans to change.

Extra bonus link to [Fences and JMM](http://old.nabble.com/AtomicXXX.lazySet-and-happens-before-reasoning-tt32568459.html#a32571494)

Comment: Probably the correct answer but do you have any references or reasons to believe so?

Comment: @owlstead Wouldn't there be a mention in the JSR if it was superseeded/updated?

Comment: yeah, can dig up later the exact ref.; in jsr166 mailing list there was a question on doug lea's fences API, and if the memory model would be deprecated in favor of fences (in case they managed to get pushed into public API), it was quite clear the current memory model is here to stay (i.e. no changes)

Comment: References to Doug always score points - seems legit, so up you go :)

Comment: @owlstead, added the link too